# eclipse project are not found help me

Tags: java, eclipse

I try to import a project with `File`->`Import`->`Existing Projects into Workspace` into my eclipse workspace but it says that `No projects are found to import`. What can I  do?

[image]

Comment: A bit more information would help. For example, are you trying to import an existing eclipse project? Trying to import a directory that contains code but is not a previously created eclipse project?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! What is the title of the view that you are looking at? `Project Explorer`? What happens if you execute from the menu `File` -> `New Project` and create a new project with that function?

Comment: Either there are no projects in the selected folder, or you disabled recursive searching and the specific project is nested some ways inside the selected folder

Comment: What kind of projects do you try to import?

Comment: Which eclipse version do you use and which function did you use? Was it the `Existing Projects into Workspace` function? For this you need to have a `.project` file in the selected folder.

Comment: an Eclipse project is defined by .project file inside the folder. if you try to import sources from a folder in a new project like a maven project then eclipse will create this file for this use : import Maven Project

Comment: I downloaded the project to be imported and saved it in my desktop. On eclipse I made File -> Import -> from existing project -> and then appear these photo

Comment: which project ?

Comment: @michaeak yes I do this . how do I enter the .project file?

Comment: Import -> from existing project that means From exixting Eclipse Project . Eclipse is searching for .project file if you dont  have this folder this way will not fit

Comment: @ArnaultLePrévost-Corvellec how should i do? I'm not very practical

Comment: mickael way can fit but if you want the best way to handle that we need more information about the project itself to guide you

Comment: There are several import wizards. Use _File > Open Project from File System..._ which (if the `.project` file is missing) automatically detects if it is e. g. a Java project.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: First create a new Project with `File`->`New`->`Project` and then copy the resources to this newly created project.

Comment: the issue with this way is that project nature and build path wont be defined this will have to be manually before its project compile

Comment: What kind of project is this? Maven? Gradle? Ant?

Comment: ziped project ?

Comment: how do you know? Then use the function `File`->`Import...`->`General` ... `Archive File`